# How to target an element with random id in cypress

Tags: cypress

[How to target an element with random id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2KAv.png)

I tried to use xpath, but doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Use [`cy.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Regular-Expression) to search by text or regex alone or with a selector.

```js
cy.contains(/This text has random Id/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cy.contains` with the combination of selector and text.

```js
cy.contains('p', 'This text has random Id')
```